# Make a method which generate result for once (first time) and return while it called as it store at the first time

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. I have a little bit problem. Like, a function which calls for many times and has a complex query. This function will generate the result for the first time and store the result in a variable . when I will call this function it will return its stored result.
Suppose I have a method like

```
public function add_sum(){
$a=2;
$b=3;
return c=$a+$b;
}
```

This function will generate the result for the first time, and when I will call this function after first time.

```
$a=2;
$b=3;
return c=$a+$b;
```

this code will not be executed. without this block it will return 5. Hope guys you got my point. Calling function is..

```
public function test(){
$this->add_sum();
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Sessions aren't for storing big amounts of data. In fact, depending on your system, it may result in issues. Cookies are similar.

If your query is *big* but returns something *small* like as you suggested a number, then it is perfectly fine to store it in a session variable. If it returns something *big* like a large array, then you could consider using some sort of caching mechanism. Codeigniter has an in-built one for database caching, whose methodology I don't necessarily believe in. But this is generally how you use it if you just want to cache a few queries: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html#function-reference otherwise you can just turn db caching on in `database.php` (don't do this unless you thoroughly understand the consequences).

You could consider writing/read the results from a file, but you would have to benchmark it to see if it is faster than just performing the SQL operation.

Now to answer your specific question:

```
public function test(){
     if ($this->session->has_userdata('test_response')) {
         return $this->session->test_response;
     }
     $sum = $this->add_sum();
     $this->session->set_userdata('test_response', $sum);
     return $sum;
}
```

as you can see, on the first run the conditional statement will eval to false, `add_sum` will run, and its contents will be assigned to a session variable. on subsequent runs, this variable will be retrieved from the session immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hope it will help me which I  want.